# How to add Authorization in xhr request manually?

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, jwt, primeng

I am using primeng control for uploading file. For upload/download/delete it is working perfect. Now my requirement is to show file in some other page as hyperlink and user can click and download the file.

We are using Authorization header for authentication. I am not sure how to set authorization header manually.

This is the html for upload file

```
<div class="form-group">
              <p-fileUpload name="file" uploadLabel="Comfirm" multiple="true"
                url="{{environment.ApiPath}}/api/uploadMultiplefiles"
                (onBeforeSend)="uploadService.onBeforeSend($event)"
                (onUpload)="uploadService.onUpload($event, attachments, 'attachments', msgs)">
                <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                  <div class="ui-fileupload-row" *ngFor="let file of attachments; let i = index;">
                    <div><img [src]="file.objectURL" *ngIf="uploadService.isImage(file)" [width]="previewWidth" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="uploaded-file"
                      (click)="uploadService.downloadFile(attachments, i, 'attachments', msgs)">
                      {{file.uploadname}}</div>
                    <div>
                      <button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-danger confirm-btn"
                        (click)="uploadService.deleteFile(attachments, i, 'attachments', msgs)">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </ng-template>
              </p-fileUpload>
            </div>
```

This is code for setting JWT Authorization

```
onBeforeSend = function (event) {
    event.xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', this.JWT.getValue());
  };
```

This code is working out of the box and setting header properly and uploading/downloading file.

Now in other page user is trying to download the file and I have implemented it like this

```
<div class="form-group">
                <a target="_blank"
                  (click)="onNavigate(element.File)" href="#">{{element.File}}</a>
              </div>
```

Now my question is how to create set authorization header at this page? Because I am not getting $event here. How to call above **onBeforeSend** function here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I got no response hence posting how I resolve it.

1) Add JWT token in Angular module for getting JWT token available.

```
 providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: JWTInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }]
})
```

2) I just created a header and when header is open insert the authorization details as token.

```
private headers =new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/pdf'});
xhrReq.open(method, url); //use http.post for Angular way
this.headers.append('authorization', <token>);
```